# Unable to SSH into Pi 3 over Wi-Fi

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, ssh, ethernet, putty

I have two Pi's, one is Pi 3 Model B and the other is Pi 2 model B. I have connected the Pi's together via Ethernet. The Pi's have been assigned static IP address (modified the `dhcpcd.conf` file):

- Pi 3 (eth0 ip) --> 192.168.137.170
- Pi 2 (eth0 ip) --> 192.168.137.10

I am able to SSH from Pi 3 to Pi 2 and vice versa over the Ethernet connection.

Now, I start a Wi-Fi hotspot on Windows laptop and connect Pi 3 to it. The wlan0 IP assigned to Pi 3 is 192.168.137.33. 
(So, Pi 3 Now has two IP's eth0 and wlan0).

Now there are two cases:

- Disconnect the Ethernet connection between the Pi's, then SSH from windows (PuTTY) to Pi 3 over Wi-Fi. **This works!**
- Keeping the Ethernet connected between the two Pi's, then trying to SSH from windows (PuTTY) to Pi 3 over Wi-Fi doesn't work. PuTTY throws **"Connection timed out"** error.

I would like to SSH from windows into Pi 3 over Wi-Fi, then through this PuTTY session SSH into Pi 2 over Ethernet. Could please someone help me how to do it.

Comment: How exactly you defined eth0 and wlan0 in P3's dhcpcd.conf? What is your netmask on the router or on your P3 configuration?

Comment: @hcheung As per this [link](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update). I added these lines to the end of dhcpcd.conf file: interface eth0, static ip_address=192.168.137.170, static routers=192.168.0.1, static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

Comment: I have a similar configuration as your P3 and I can use both of eth0 and/or wlan0.

Comment: "Connection timed out" error (Point 2 of my question). I don't know why this is happening. Connecting the Ethernet seems to be conflicting with the Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: Noticed that you only have eth0 configuration in dhcpcd.conf, but no wlan0? Here is how I setup mines `interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.101
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.100
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1`. Why is your ip is `192.168.137.xxx` while your router is `192.168.0.1`? is your netmask set on your router set as `255.255.0.0`?

Comment: My mistake. I changed routers and dns to 192.168.137.xxx. But even then I am unable to solve the "Connection timed out" error.

Comment: The pi probably prefers ethernet over wifi(as it should)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in which two separate interfaces on a single machine are configured in the same network is not correct.

The situation you described is expected as the return packets from the Pi to the Windows machine might be sent through the Ethernet once it's connected (and, of course, not reach the destination).

---

Use different IP network on the Ethernet and WiFi interfaces.

It might be as easy as changing the network mask to split the 192.168.137.0 into two networks, or not. It depends on your whole network configuration.

Comment: how do you know it is two networks?

Comment: @hcheung I have no clue what you are asking about.

Comment: sorry, my misreading of your message.